# BindingSource/DataGridView interaction

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I cannot understand why my DataGridView keeps on being empty (no rows, no autogenerated columns):

```
BindingList<MyObject> bList = new BindingList<MyObject>();
 fileStream.Position = 0;
 MyObject.Deserialize(fileStream).ForEach(
     j => bList.Add(j));

 this.bindingSource1.SuspendBinding();

 this.dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
 this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
 this.dataGridView1.Enabled = false;
 this.dataGridView1.Invalidate();
 this.bindingSource1.DataSource = bList;
 this.dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
 this.bindingSource1.ResumeBinding();
 this.dataGridView1.Enabled = true;
 this.dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

where MyObject is defined as

```
public class MyObject
{
    public DateTime CreationDate;
    public string CreationId;

    public static List<MyObject> Deserialize(Stream s)
    {
        XDocument xml = XDocument.Load(s);

        var ps = from p in xml
                      .Descendants("p")
                      .Descendants("object")
                  select
                      new MyObject
                      {
                          CreationId = p.Attribute("creationid").Value
                      };

        return ps.ToList();
    }

}
```

In addition if I explicitily set columns as below, rows are added to the grid but they are all empty

```
DataGridViewTextBoxColumn dc = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            dc.DataPropertyName = "CreationDate";
            dc.HeaderText = "CreationDate";
            dc.Name = "CreationDate";
            dc.Visible = true;
            dc.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dc);

            dc = new DataGridViewTextBoxColumn();
            dc.DataPropertyName = "CreationId";
            dc.HeaderText = "CreationId";
            dc.Name = "CreationId";
            dc.Visible = true;
            dc.AutoSizeMode = DataGridViewAutoSizeColumnMode.Fill;
            this.dataGridView1.Columns.Add(dc);
```

Comment: Just quick observations - 1. Try to Rename 'creationid' as `CreationId` exactly like grid view's `DataProperty` and `CreationDate` is missing in the Object.

Comment: Above comment is valid only if the `Autogeneratecolumn is set to false` --> scenario

Comment: False. creationid is written in that way in the xml. Your solution wouldn't work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In a Winforms project, try this code (kind of simulator of what you have posted & `it works !`) & then map / debug to your existing code to narrow down the problem:-

```
    DataGridView dgv = new DataGridView();
    //Note: AutogenerateColumns is true by default
    BindingSource bs = new BindingSource();
    BindingList<Customer> bList = new BindingList<Customer>();

    // Fill bList with Customers
    bList.Add(new Customer(){Name="John"});

    bs.DataSource = bList;
    dgv.DataSource = bs;

    this.Controls.Add(dgv);
```

> **MyObject** equivalent **:-**

```
public class Customer
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }
```

---

So, `to Debug your code` *by mapping to the above one*, you may **remove** these bits -

```
 this.bindingSource1.SuspendBinding();
 this.dataGridView1.Columns.Clear();
 this.dataGridView1.AutoGenerateColumns = true;
 this.dataGridView1.Enabled = false;
 this.dataGridView1.Invalidate();
 this.bindingSource1.ResumeBinding();
 this.dataGridView1.Enabled = true;
 this.dataGridView1.Refresh();
```

& `just have this` in the 1st trial -

```
 this.bindingSource1.DataSource = bList;
 this.dataGridView1.DataSource = bindingSource1;
```

Comment: You should have pointed out better that I was missing {get; set;} but +1 for quick answer